# How to use lookup fields using RegExp for search bar in LWC data-table?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, regular-expressions

Here's the link to the similar question
[How to filter Data in dataTable lwc based on the input in search bar?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306284/how-to-filter-data-in-datatable-lwc-based-on-the-input-in-search-bar/370164#370164)

The above works fine with non-lookup fields but doesn't seem to be working in my case.

If I use `regex.test(row.Name)`, I'm able to search the records based on Name column however, one of my columns has `fieldName: Owner.Name` and the search isn't working.

> Error: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')]

.js code snippet:

```javascript
updateSearch(event) {
     var regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'i')
     this.data = this.testSearch.filter(
        row => regex.test(row.Owner.Name) 
     );
```

Any idea on above?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to be working", exactly? How are we supposed to help you if we don't know exactly what's wrong?

Comment: @sfdcfox I meant the search isn't working, updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Owner.Name as a fieldName in Columns do this:

Old format:

```
{ label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'Owner.Name'}
```

New format:

```
{ label: 'Owner', fieldName: 'Owner'}
```

and Update the code to include Owner.Name in your array of columns like below:

```
this.data = data.map((row) => ({ Owner: row.Owner.Name }));
```

this will make the search method as:

```
updateSearch(event) {
     var regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'i')
     this.data = this.testSearch.filter(
        row => regex.test(row.Owner) 
     );
}
```

This is working fine for me.